# cant resolve method "clear()" in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

Am trying to update my recycler view with the data which i get from MOVIE db API. Am using ASYNC task to make the request and get the result from the server, but in the onPostExecute() when i try to clear the adapter and add the new data to the adapter it is showing a "cannot  resolve method 'clear()' "

MAINACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static QueryUtils queryUtils = new QueryUtils();
    final static String URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?    api_key=";
    static String[] finalData = new        String[queryUtils.getLengthOfJsonArray(URL)];
    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
        //using the grid layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        //setting the adpater.
        mAdapter = new MovieAdapter(finalData, this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        MovieTask task =new MovieTask();
        task.execute(URL);    
    }

    private class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            String[] data = queryUtils.fetchMovieData(URL);
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] data) {
            mAdapter.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

MOVIE-ADAPTER ACITIVITY

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private String[] adumyString;
    private int[] adumyimage;
    private Context context;

    //Constructor for Movie Adapter
    public MovieAdapter(String[] dummyDataSet,Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        adumyString=dummyDataSet;
    }

    // Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
    // Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        public ImageView colorImageView;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row.
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);
            colorImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Binds the data into
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(adumyString[position]).into(holder.colorImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adumyString.length;
    }

    /**
     * Inflates the out custom view on to the screen.
     */
    @Override
    public MovieAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_view,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: RecyclerView.Adapter does not have method `clear()`. You have to implement it before using

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView.Adapter` abstract class doesn't provide any `clear` or `add` method. See the documentation for the class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html).

You have to declare and implement these methods in your `MovieAdapter` class and declare your `mAdapter` variable as `MovieAdapter mAdapter;`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` in your `onPostExecute()` method .

ps : Sorry for writing comment here , low rep :)